# Alternative for Session["variable"] in FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

We are using `FormsAuthentication` for a login process.
I need to add some data to the Logged in users Session to use in all the pages.

It can be done using `Session["variable"] = value`, but I read few articles that said not to use session variables with `FormsAuthentication`.

Is there any similar alternative like `Session["variable"]` to use with `FormsAuthentication`?

Comment: There isn't an alternative to `Session` but you can have `alternative`  of authentication and authorization APIs - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/security

Comment: Can you link any of the articles that advised against using session state specifically in conjunction with forms authentication?  I'd be curious as to the reasons they cite.

The only reason I could think is to avoid putting sensitive data regarding the logged in user, in which case that isn't an issue with using session state, its an issue of where you are storing that session state (cookies versus in memory or distributed caches)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [UserData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [FormsAuthenticationTicket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata(v=vs.110).aspx), which is created, encrypted, and stored in the forms cookie if you are using ASP.NET forms authentication.  The very purpose of this field is to store free form data of the sort you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Using private key to encrypt data and store in cookie can be an alternative. For every request, you can perform checking by reading and decrypt (with the private key) the cookie variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there's a way with javascript that is localStorage or SessionStorge

```
window.localStorage.setItem("message", "Hello World!");
```